# Is "to" a prefix in English?

Tags: prefixes

I was thinking about the words "today" and "tonight" and trying to think of what "to" means in these words. A cursory Google search turns up no results for "to-" in any prefix lists.

Comment: [**today**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=today) *Old English **todæge, to dæge** "**on** (this) day," from **to "at, on"** (see **to**) + **dæge**, dative of **dæg** "day" (see **day**). Meaning "in modern times" is from c.1300. As a noun from 1530s. Generally written as two words until 16c., after which it usually was written **to-day** until early 20c.*

Comment: Net:  It behaves as a prefix for a few words, but if you were to use it as a prefix for some arbitrary word the construction is not likely to be well-understood.  (Nor would it be well-tolerated by English teachers and editors.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, why a comment, when yours is an equally succinct answer to the one accepted.

Comment: @eve_niggle: I just quoted the relevant chunk from the etymonline entry for **today**, which as you say is "succinct". I haven't actually voted on this page, but in my book that should really be reason enough to closevote as "General Reference/No evidence of prior research", regardless of what OP thinks a "cursory Google search" means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**to (a prep.) :**
Old English to "in the direction of, for the purpose of[.....](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=to&allowed_in_frame=0)

> Commonly used as a prefix in Middle English (to-hear "listen to,"
>   etc.), but few of these survive (to-do, together, and time references
>   such as **today, tonight, tomorrow** -- Chaucer also has to-yeere). 
>   [(etymonline)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=to&allowed_in_frame=0)

Answer (score -1):

No, at least I can't find evidence for "to-" being a prefix.  It is not stressed, like some prefixes ("consider", ...), but since it ends in a lax vowel, you wouldn't expect it to be stressed, anyhow (compare "toboggan", "Topeka").  Some Latinate prefixes cause voicing of a following "s" ("design", "exist", "resist"), but I can't think of any forms where this might happen after "to-".

(It should be clear that the etymology of this "to-" cannot tell us whether it is a prefix in current English.)

Comment: Can you please substantiate your argument.

Comment: Do you mean the last statement, @eve_niggle?  Etymology does not tell about the present language system, because languages change.  Current English is not Old English.